# Child div elements not appearing in parent div element created by JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started learning JavaScript about a few weeks ago, and I have a problem. I have here two functions that are meant to bring up a menu when a button is clicked. In theory the menu that pops up should bring up a small div element from the left side, and 6 div elements within that div element. The main div element has the id "pokemonswitch" and when I click the button with the related function it only brings up "pokemonswitch" the other div elements don't seem to want to appear inside "pokemonswitch". I have tinkered with the code and have gotten various results.

1: Div elements appear in "pokemonswitch as programmed but after I click another button that removes "pokemonwitch" the div elements remain there despite the parent element not being there.

2: The div elements do not appear at all within "pokemonswitch".

3: The div elements appear in random places and the rest of the function doesn't work.

My goal is to have a function that calls up "pokemonswitch" with six div elements inside of it. Is there something I am missing about structure that is causing my child div elements to act so crazy? I hope this is clear enough to be answered, if not I will be more than happy to append more details to the problem.

```
//MAKE DIV ELEMENT pokemonswitch VISIBLE AND ASSOCIATIVE SLOTS AS WELL
 function pkmnFunction() {
     var element = document.getElementById('pokemonswitch');
     var cancel = document.getElementById('optionsdiv');


     element.style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById('slot1').style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById('slot2').style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById('slot3').style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById('slot4').style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById('slot5').style.visibility = "visible";
     document.getElementById('slot6').style.visibility = "visible";
     cancel.innerHTML = "<input id='cancelbutton' type='button' value='cancel' onclick='canFunction()' style='position:absolute; top:95px; left:35px;'></input>";
     element.innerHTML = "<div id='slot1'></div><div id='slot2'></div><div id='slot3'></div><div id='slot4'></div><div id='slot5'></div><div id='slot6'></div>";
 }

 //MAKE DIV ELEMENT pokemonswitch HIDDEN AND ASSOCIATED slot ELEMENTS AS WELL               
 function canFunction() {
     var element = document.getElementById('pokemonswitch');
     var cancel = document.getElementById('optionsdiv');



     document.getElementById('slot1').style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById('slot2').style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById('slot3').style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById('slot4').style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById('slot5').style.visibility = "hidden";
     document.getElementById('slot6').style.visibility = "hidden";
     element.style.visibility = "hidden"

     cancel.innerHTML = "<input id='b5' type='button' onclick='setSlots()' value='Check Slot' ></input><input id='b1' type='button' value='Fight!'></input><input id='b2' type='button' onclick='pkmnFunction()' value='Pkmn'></input><input id='b3' type='button' value='Items' onclick='itemFunction()'></input><input id='b4' type='button' value='Run'></input>";

 }

 ////////////ASSOCIATED CSS STYLE CODE//////////////////

 #pokemonswitch {
     position: absolute;
     width: 180px;
     margin - left: -15px;
     height: 100 % ;
     border: solid;
     border - color: black;
     border - width: 2px;
     border - radius: 25px;
     background - color: 0099CC;
     z - index: 3;
     visibility: hidden;
 }

 #slot1 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: -10px;
     padding: 5px;
     text - align: center;
     border: solid;
     border - width: 1px;
     background - color: red;
     width: 170px;
     height: 65px;
     z - index: 4;

 }


 #slot2 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 65px;
     left: -10px;
     padding: 5px;
     text - align: center;
     border: solid;
     border - width: 1px;
     background - color: red;
     width: 170px;
     height: 65px;
     z - index: 4;
     visibility: hidden;
 }


 #slot3 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 130px;
     left: -500px;
     padding: 5px;
     text - align: center;
     border: solid;
     border - width: 1px;
     background - color: red;
     width: 170px;
     height: 65px;
     z - index: 4;
     visibility: hidden;
 }


 #slot4 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 195px;
     left: -500px;
     padding: 5px;
     text - align: center;
     border: solid;
     border - width: 1px;
     background - color: red;
     width: 170px;
     height: 65px;
     z - index: 4;
     visibility: hidden;
 }


 #slot5 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 260px;
     left: -500px;
     padding: 5px;
     text - align: center;
     border: solid;
     border - width: 1px;
     background - color: red;
     width: 170px;
     height: 65px;
     z - index: 4;
     visibility: hidden;
 }

 #slot6 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 325px;
     left: -250px;
     padding: 5px;
     text - align: center;
     border: solid;
     border - width: 1px;
     background - color: red;
     width: 170px;
     height: 65px;
     z - index: 4;
     visibility: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Do you need it in Javascript? Because you could just write the menu in HTML and give it a `display:none` in CSS. And then you just need to `display:block` to show it.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ? - what does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, you are trying to refer an element that isn't even created yet.

```
element.innerHTML = "<div id='slot1'></div><div id='slot2'></div><div id='slot3'></div><div id='slot4'></div><div id='slot5'></div><div id='slot6'></div>";//Place this first
document.getElementById('slot1').style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('slot2').style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('slot3').style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('slot4').style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('slot5').style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('slot6').style.visibility = "visible";
cancel.innerHTML = "<input id='cancelbutton' type='button' value='cancel' onclick='canFunction()' style='position:absolute; top:95px; left:35px;'></input>";
```

Also few other things I noticed were:

Instead of using `style.visibility` use `style.display`. `<input>` isn't a container element, so remove `</input>` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('slot1').style.visibility = "visible";
element.innerHTML = "<div id='slot1'></div>";
```

This is not right. The first line suggests that an element with id `slot` already exists. The second line adds a new div with that same id.

If the element should already exist, you can add the existing element

```
var slot1 = document.getElementById('slot1');
slot1.style.visibility = "visible";
element.appendChild(slot);
```

If not, you can create it first:

```
var slot1 = document.createElement('div');
slot1.id = 'slot1';
slot1.style.visibility = "visible";
element.appendChild(slot);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way! Create a div that contains the form you want and make this div display:none. Then on click make it visible where you want to

```
<div style="display:none">
<div id="mycontent">
content content
</div>
</div>
```

then use
document.getElementById('ID')..style.display="value"